# Handling updates and deletes with ViewModels in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, concurrency, viewmodel

I seem to have some problems wrapping my head around the concept about how to best handle updating and deleting from lists in MVC. I'll try to explain my problem with a short example. From the Entity Framework I have my object Position:

```
public int Quantity { get; set; }

public int PositionNumber { get; set; }

public string ArticleNumber { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; }

public string Remark { get; set; }
```

Now I've heard that it's best to make a ViewModel foreach View with the used properties so to make it simple the ViewModel looks the same. In the controller we return a list of Positions to the view by mapping the Model to the ViewModel.
Now the view displays textboxes for Quantity and Remark which the user can change. He can also delete a position.
Now when posting the data the user entered I do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<ShoppingCartPositionModel> shoppingCartPositions)
    {
        var positions = _shoppingCartManager.GetActiveShoppingCart().Positions.Values.OrderBy(p => p.PositionNumber).ToList();

        if (FormCollection.AllKeys.Any(k => k.Contains("Remove")))
        {
            string key = FormCollection.AllKeys.Where(k => k.Contains("Remove")).First();
            int start = key.LastIndexOf('[') + 1;
            int end = key.LastIndexOf(']');
            int difference = end - start;

            int index;
            if (int.TryParse(key.Substring(start, difference), out index))
            {
                _shoppingCartManager.DeleteShoppingCartPosition(positions.ElementAt(index));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < positions.Count(); i++)
                {
                    var position = positions.ElementAt(i);
                    var cartPosition = shoppingCartPositions.ElementAt(i);

                    position.PositionNumber = cartPosition.PositionNumber;
                    position.Quantity = cartPosition.Quantity;
                    position.Remark = cartPosition.Remark;
                }

                _shoppingCartManager.UpdateShoppingCartPositions(positions);
            }
        }

        var cartPositions = GetShoppingCartPositionsModel();
        UpdateModel(cartPositions);

        return View(cartPositions.ToList());
    }
```

My problem is how will this work if in the meantime another user has deleted an object or even added a new position inbetween the others? Would it be best to make a hidden field on the view and map by that? And to detect updates save a changed date and display a hidden field on the view for that aswell? Because I think if I'd simply check the date update like this I would always have the newest update date and I don't think in the few seconds the service needs to update an item any other user can change the data.
I hope this explaines my issue and thanks to those trying to help me find a way to do this.

Comment: Why do you want to do a post the form to delete the entity? Can you not just use a different action (like cart/delete/id). Then you could handle the case when another user already deleted the item within this action.

Comment: Do you mean a link? The problem is that the whole shopping cart is either updated (quantity etc.) or a single item is deleted. And I don't want to make a form inside a form to call a different post action if possible.

Comment: Yeah, that was my intention. I don't think you can do nested forms. The nicest way would be to have an AJAX call in case JavaScript is available. But in your case that would get a bit complicated. The link doesn't work either because the user would loose his changes if you don't post back. Still thinking about it... In the meantime: try to simplify your question, you might get more attention. Main problem is not the ViewModel, but the update and deletion of your shopping cart positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem you seem to have is that you have different actions on the same form. Would it help if you could handle the submit buttons for delete and update by different actions? There is a nice solution [about this here](http://blog.ashmind.com/2010/03/15/multiple-submit-buttons-with-asp-net-mvc-final-solution/).

The other point is the detection of possible changes by other users in the meantime. What about a hidden field on the view with the last update time of the whole data structure? If it is still the same on postback, nobody has touched the data.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like a good soultion, I will try it out as soon as possible =)